# How come there is only one solution to $\sqrt{110-n} = n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:
$\sqrt{110-n} = n$

It follows that:

$110 - n = n^2$

$n^2 + n - 110 = 0$

$(n + 11)(n - 10)=0$

If $n = 10$, $\sqrt{110 - 10} = \sqrt{100} = 10$, it checks out.

If $n = -11$, $\sqrt{110 - (-11)} = \sqrt{121} = 11$, it doesn't

However!

I thought that $\sqrt{x}$ gives you two possible numbers, $+\sqrt{x}$ and $-\sqrt{x}$, so in the example above, $\sqrt{121} = -11$ is a valid root.

Can someone explain what's going on here? Why aren't they both valid?

Comment: Note that your sentence: "I thought that $\sqrt x$ gives you two possible numbers $+\sqrt x$ and $-\sqrt x $", is not correct. $\sqrt x $ has 2 solutions $(+y)$ and (or) $(-y)$ where $y^2 = x$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you squared, you introduced a second solution. Consider a much simpler problem: $\sqrt 4=n$. This has the unique solution $n=2$. If you square both sides, however, you get $4=n^2$, which has two solutions, $n=2$ and $n=-2$. The second is not a solution of $\sqrt4=n$, because the square root symbol by convention means the non-negative square root: when you use it, you’re implicitly choosing one of the solutions to the squared equation. Similarly, there are two integers $n$ with the property that $110-n=n^2$, $10$ and $-11$, but when you write $n=\sqrt{110-n}$, you’re forcing $n$ to be non-negative and thereby eliminating one of the two solutions to $110-n=n^2$.

Comment: The convention of it meaning a non-negative was exactly what I needed to hear, thank you Brian (I will accept when stackexchange lets me)

Comment: @Henry: Actually you correctly wrote yourself "It follws that:" and not "This is equivalent to:" when you squared.

Answer (score 7):

It just has to do with the fact that $(-n)^2 = (n)^2$ does not imply that $-n = n$.

The $\sqrt{n}$ can only be positive by definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can *pinpoint* the error by working backwards, finding the first equation which doesn't hold for the value $\rm\:n = -11.\:$ You'll find that all equations except the first hold true for $\rm\:n= -11,\:$ so your inference from the first to the second equation must be erroneous. The problem is that you applied to the first equation a non $1$-to-$1$ operation (squaring), which  generally *enlarges* its solution set, introducing [*extraneous* solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61353/242)

This method of isolating errors works quite generally. It is especially useful when debugging proofs on *abstract* objects, since the error may become simpler to locate after specializing to more *concrete* objects. Above, evaluating all equations at $\rm\,n=-11\,$ has the effect of specializing the arithmetic of polynomial and algebraic functions (in $\rm\,n)\,$ to the simpler arithmetic of integers, making the error much easier to locate. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/152860/242) for further discussion.