# How to find the error in a proof of Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Someone posted an interesting number theory question earlier. I think I'm making a mistake with Fermat's Little Theorem, but I"m not sure how.

Original problem, find $x$, $y$, $z$ natural numbers so that $7^x+13^y=2^{3z}$.

One obvious solution is $x=1$, $y=0$, and $z=1$.

Re-expressing the equation modulo 7 implies $y$ is even.

Given $y$ is even then the equation in modulo 8 implies $x$ is odd.

Modulo 13, 2 and 7 are multiplicative inverses.

So $7^{x+3z}=1 \pmod{13}$

By Fermat's Little Theorem, it follows that $x+3z=0 \pmod{12}$

But this congruence is not satisfied if x=1 and z=1, a known solution to the problem.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Mathjax note: the syntax for modulo is `\pmod{13}` , also use `\equiv` rather than equality sign.

Comment: (It's not at all essential to use the three-line symbol for things being equal mod whatever, by this year, since the modifier "mod whatever" makes clear that the equality is not the most elementary/naive one.)

Comment: Also note you've applied Fermat's little theorem incorrectly.  While it is true that $$7^x \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \implies x \equiv 0 \pmod{12},$$ this is not Fermat's little theorem, which is the converse.  The implication you used (the converse of Fermat's little theorem) is equivalent to the claim $7$ is a primitive root modulo $13$.

Comment: As explained in the proposed dupe [How to find the error in a proof? (that $1=0$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152742/proof-that-1-0-why-is-it-false) the way to debug such a proof is to find the first line that is false for your known solution $x,y,z = 1,0,1$. That is the line claiming $\,7^{x+3z}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and it is clear why: you assumed $13^y\equiv 0\pmod{13},\,$ which fails when $\,y = 0.\ \ $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the error in a proof? (that $1=0$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152742/how-to-find-the-error-in-a-proof-that-1-0)

Comment: The proposed dupe is **not** applicable to this question.

Comment: @amWhy It seems you missed my prior comment which clearly explains how **it is** applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that $13^y$ is divisible by $13$ which is wrong for $y=0$. So your claim $7^{x+3z}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ is incorrect.